# random instances of map-coloring in python

Tags: python, graph-coloring

I need to generate random instances of map coloring problem in python to implement a min-conflict solver. I should follow this strategy: scatter n points on the unit square; select a point X at random, connect X by a line segment to the nearest point Y such that X is not already connected to Y and the segment crosses no other segment (see, e.g., here how to test for segment-segment intersection); repeat the previous step until no more connections are possible. The points represent regions on the map and the lines connect neighbors. 
I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Start with a piece of code that will select your `n` points on a square, that shouldn't be hard if you know at least basics of Python. Next, write three functions: segment-segment intersection checker, distance calculator, function that given X returns you Y that is closest to X and not connected to X, and can be connected according to rules. If you have problem with any of those functions ask another question providing more details and showing what you've tried.

Comment: The thing I'm struggling with is how to represent the square. Is a 2d list too naive?

Comment: That depends, how big is the "square unit" and how many points are you going to pick from it. I'd personally skip representation of the "field" entirely and only keep the graph nodes as objects with coordinates. Then use a dictionary of dictionaries for quick access to them or some other convenient collection.

Answer (score 0):

Something for you to start, take this class:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.neighbours = set()

  def is_neighbour(node: Node):
    return node in self.neighbours

  def connect(node: Node):
    self.neighbours.add(node)
    node.neighbours.add(self)

  def distance(node: Node):
    return ((self.x - node.x)**2 + (self.y - node.y)**2)**0.5
```

The hardest part will be detecting if the connection between points you're trying to make won't cross with another connection, but I'll leave it to you.